# Getting Data from a SOAP envelope

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2007, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am trying to populate a gadget with a sharepoint list, but I couldn't find any way or tutorial on google to help me with this, however I find this tutorial that is getting the XML feedbacks of a news website, and displaying them in a list.

[Tutorial for Making a Gadget that gets XML feedbacks off a news Site](http://vishsharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/get-sharepoint-list-data-using.html)

Now Instead of getting XML feedback from that News Website, I want this tutorial to display items of XML document I will get throught this piece of code,

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> 
            <soapenv:Body> 
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> 
                    <listName>ListName</listName> 
                    <viewFields> 
                        <ViewFields> 
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> 
                       </ViewFields> 
                    </viewFields> 
                </GetListItems> 
            </soapenv:Body> 
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://my_site/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset="utf-8""
    });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\:row").each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
    });
}
```

I got no clue about how can i do this trick, but please can you atleast just guide me, how can i accomplish this task, + what things should i look into or learn, as google is not helping me with my queries at all :/.

Comment: Which versionof SharePoint are you using? SharePoint 2010 has a client library for JavaScript.

Comment: Hi John, I am using 2007 in this context

Comment: That blog post appears to be for SP2010 (at least from the title).

Comment: @JohnSaunders If you keep going down the blog, it has two solutions to the problem, one is for 2010 (first one) and second one is a SOAP envelop which can be used any where regardless of platform :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using soap requests and query through `/_vti_bin/lists.asmx` good option is to use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) library, which is a simplest way to get data without digging into soap requests. there are many simple examples, try it out!

But, if it is compulsory to stick to soap implementation, there are two tools that can help you `soapUI` and `fiddler`.

with the help of soapUI, you will be able to create a soap request easily from url you have. You can inspect request and response using fiddler.

Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: Thanks alot Prashant, I dont really have to use SOAP, I looked into that library before, I seen examples that are being used in ASP.NET but coudn't find a way to use them in my Windows 7 Gadget :), if you know any tutorial using them in a gadget please let me know at the same time I am looking as well